# How to disable the save function

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro which does data mining and saves the workbook in the end. I intend to disable to the save function of the workbook and force the user to use the macro everytime the workbook needs to be saved. This is what I have so far but it does not seem to work. When I do this, my macro and this sub described below are both running in a loop. every time my macro tries to save the workbook, this sub is not allowing it. I basically want to force the user to use the macro to save the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NoSave

    NoSave = MsgBox("Changes have to be submitted before the workbook can be saved, Proceed and submit ?", vbYesNo, "Continue?")

    If NoSave = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Main
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not just take the save part out of your Macro, and run your Macro on the BeforeSave event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an Example. Paste this in `ThisWorkbook`. This will not let you use the `Save` or the `SaveAs`. You can however use the macro `SaveThisFile` to save the workbook. Please amend it to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Dim SaveByCode As Boolean
Const msg As String = "Please use the macro to save the file"

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Me.Saved = False And SaveByCode = False Then
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Unable to save"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If SaveByCode = True Then
        SaveThisFile
    Else
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Unable to save"
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'~~> Your macro to save the file
Sub SaveThisFile()
    SaveByCode = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: If your Save macro is in a module then remove this `Dim SaveByCode As Boolean` from `ThisWorkbook` and place `Public SaveByCode As Boolean` in a module.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, how about this (I misunderstood the question at first, but also wanted to give it a try since it's interesting):
Declare public boolean (exceptional) in the thisworkbook module:

```
Option Explicit
Public bSave As Boolean
```

In the event BeforeSave event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim sNoSave As String

If bSave = True Then
    bSave = False
    Exit Sub
End If

sNoSave = MsgBox("Changes have to be submitted before the workbook can be saved, Proceed and submit ?", vbYesNo, "Continue?")

If sNoSave = vbNo Then
    bSave = False
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    bSave = True
    Call Main(bSave)
End If

End Sub
```

In Main:

Option Explicit

```
Sub Main(bSave)

If bSave = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\Book1.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    MsgBox "Main method called"
End If

End Sub
```